# Mac Set variable at boot time

Tags: macos, bash, variables, plist

I am trying to set an environment variable on a Mac at boot time. I want the variable to exist even if nobody is logged in. This is because I may use ARD to launch a script remotely (as root) and I need to query these variables.

I can create a *PLIST* in the *LaunchDaemons* folder that will perform *launchctl* command, but this doesn't seem to set the variable for the script that is launched remotely as root (whether someone is logged in or not). However, if a user logs in, it does work for that user.

```
launchctl setenv ENVNAME ENVVALUE
```

Information I have found on this (such as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks) suggests that it can only be in a user context, on login.

Is anyone aware of a way that a variable can be set so it exists when the **machine is booted**?

I have found details that are out of date for 10.10 (such as using the .profile or bashrc) which may have helped previously (but I can't be sure).

Comment: If the remote scripts are run by root, would it be sufficient to have these env vars set for the root user?

Comment: This is not programming question

Comment: Maybe make a file in, say `/etc/envvars` with `export VAR=fred` in it, then *"dot that in"* to your scripts with `. /etc/envvars`.

Comment: If you remote script is bash, you can add the exported variable to `/etc/profile`, and then every bash session will have it.

Comment: @xhuso00, actually a script will be creating the variables (plist in my example) and other scripts will be reading from it. Whilst the concept is not programming related, it revolves around programming methods, but happy to move elsewhere. I thought programmers would have more insight for resolving the issue due to the nature of how the variables need to be accessed.

Comment: @Jan Gassen, I want to have the ability for users to run scripts that could reference these variables too. In fact, I would like any program to be able to reference them, but I am approaching this from a scripting POV first.

Comment: @glenn jackman, added exported var to /etc/profile, but stil not available remotely (but does appear in logged users with printenv).

Comment: @Mark Setchell, this works... although it's not something that other apps could natively interrogate (whereas a proper envvar is). However I appreciate that require wouldn't be targeting the programming community. I suppose my scripts that set the envvars could add this envvar file AND set the setenv settings. Doubling up, but perhaps there is no other choice.